# Bash trap command failing to catch fatal php script exit code 255

Tags: php, bash, signals, posix, bash-trap

Minimal example of the issue:

```
#!/bin/bash

errHandler() {
    echo "Something went wrong. Exiting now."
    exit 1
}
trap 'errHandler' ERR INT

pi_process () {
    bin/pi $@
    echo $?
}

pi_process stuff
```

bin/pi is a php script, it's exiting with exit code 255 and a fatal error. However the bash trap isn't being caught. How come?

Comment: Can you replace `bin/pi $@` by `false` ? to see if trap is caught.

Comment: Thanks, seems like my minimal example was too minimal, in my actual script, false doesn't get caught, in the minimal example it does

Comment: I've edited the example @Philippe, now when you replace with false, false isn't caught either. It seems to be because it's in a function call?

Comment: @Shardj the return value of your function is the return value of the last command, in this case, `echo`

Comment: @jordanm I don't really care what the return value is, I'm simply expecting the trap to catch but it isn't. Anyway, thank to philippe I've figured out the answer so I'll post that

Comment: @Shardj pretty sure the trap would catch if the `echo` wasn't there, but I haven't tested

Comment: Yes, but that would catch because the functions exit code is bad, which isn't what I want. I want it to catch on the bin/pi command failing. This is just a minimal example so sorry if that wasn't clear, there's lots of other stuff in the function in the real script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set -o functrace` does not seem to do what you expected.

Try this :

```
#! /bin/bash

set -e

errHandler() {
    echo "Something went wrong. Exiting now."
    exit 1
}
trap 'errHandler' EXIT

pi_process () {
    false
    echo $?
}

pi_process stuff
```

Comment: Thanks, you're correct actually, functrace just means it waits until the end of the function before dying while yours dies immediately which is far better